# Why do my mouse properties pop up when i try starting my program using the "main" command?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-code, makefile, sdl-2

I am using mingw and visual stuido code to make my first SDL2 project with c++. I have my makefile with the stuff that gotta be loaded, some dll's and my main.cpp file. When i first go with the "make" command stuff works fine, no errors, but when i then do the "main" command to run my program the mouse properties window pops up, and no SDL window.

This feels so random but I dont know how to fix it. I tried using ".\\main" instead of "main", and that worked fine. What is wrong? And also what's the difference between "main" and ".\\main"?

[image: Makefile]

[image: main.cpp]

[image: make works]

[image: Mouse properties]

[image: .\main]

Comment: This is more of a powershell question than a programming question, it doesn't run executables from the current directory by default and is picking a different executable called main off your path instead ([`C:\Windows\system32\main.cpl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/description-of-control-panel-cpl-files-4dc809cd-5063-6c6d-3bee-d3f18b2e0176))

Comment: Thanks Alan! Could you post this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)